# diffcoeff \dl not upright

Tags: diffcoeff

this is my first time posting here.
Following general advice, I decided to dump the `physics` package and replace it with alternatives like `diffcoeff`. `diffcoeff` is working fine so far, however the differential d is not upright when using `dl`.
Minimal example:

```
\documentclass[11pt,parskip]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 

\usepackage{diffcoeff}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
    \dl d
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
    \diff{x}{y}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Result:
[image]

clearly, the `\dl` and d are not distinguishable.
How do I get them to be upright as in the documentation?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: update, it works ok for me on a current texlive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With version 4 of `diffcoeff` to get an upright d you need to use the ISO package option: `\usepackage[ISO]{diffcoeff}`. With the recently released version 5, the upright d is the default.

Comment: Thanks a lot, using the options works!